# Why do opencart forms use enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Tags: php, forms, opencart, multipartform-data

For example lets say currency module's view file `currency.tpl`. It has no input of type file, but still the form is using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

I tried to remove the `enctype`, so the default one, `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is also working.

**But every Opencart form is using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. What is the reason for this?**

### EDIT

Here is the currency.tpl of opencart version 1.5.6.4

```
<?php if (count($currencies) > 1) { ?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="currency"><?php echo $text_currency; ?><br />
    <?php foreach ($currencies as $currency) { ?>
    <?php if ($currency['code'] == $currency_code) { ?>
    <?php if ($currency['symbol_left']) { ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $currency['title']; ?>"><b><?php echo $currency['symbol_left']; ?></b></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $currency['title']; ?>"><b><?php echo $currency['symbol_right']; ?></b></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php if ($currency['symbol_left']) { ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $currency['title']; ?>" onclick="$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $currency['code']; ?>'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();"><?php echo $currency['symbol_left']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $currency['title']; ?>" onclick="$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $currency['code']; ?>'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();"><?php echo $currency['symbol_right']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
  </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

What is the need of using multipart/form-data here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean TL;DR: it `means that no characters will be encoded.`

Comment: @Forien i know when to use multipart/form-data. I want to know why opencart forms are using it as apparently there is no file type input fields, so what is the reason of not to encode characters in opencart. I think i still didn't get how forms in opencart work. Explanation of it will help.

Comment: They work totally normal. And I don't think there is a reason to use `multipart/form-data`. But there is also no reason to not use it.

Answer (score 2):

As Forien mentioned,

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encodes the special characters (like `&`, `'`, `"` etc.)

`multipart/form-data` will not encode any character. This is mostly used for files (uploads) so they don't get screwed up.

Comment: Please look at the currency.tpl for example, and tell me where any file is being uploaded. I don't see any file is being uploaded there.

Comment: As I said, it is mostly used for uploads. Not always :)

Comment: No file upload is happening, they still use it. Please check my edit of the question , i have provided a sample code.

Comment: As I tried to explain, it is not bound to file uploads. You can use it any other desired way. If you don't want it, see http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2305

Comment: There has to be some reason of why every forms in opencart uses it by default.I want to know how forms are being handled here so that it is better to use multipart/form-data in form tag.

Comment: @user1906399 There is no reason to use `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And no reason to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `multipart/form-data`. They are handled the same as long as you use $_POST and other stuff handling requests

Comment: @Forien i don't think they are handled the same way, multipar/form-data is more complex to handle, so kind of burden to use if there is no file type input fields.

Comment: @user1906399 do you have a reason to use `if ($var == true)` instead of `if ($var)`? It's more complex, puts more burden on interpreter etc. But there is no logic reason to say that `if ($var == true)` should be avoided (even in big apps difference is meaningless). Same goes for enctypes of forms. And it's easier to autogenerate forms when you don't have to worry about additional variable.